# Truss Plate Loose where rafters meet

Tags: roof

DIYer here. I noticed that (only) one of the truss plates popped off where the rafters meet at the peak of the roof. Thus, a single set of rafters and the supporting beam are misligned and no longer connected.
- whats the probable reason this happened?
- If this is the only instance of the issue, is the solution simple enough? (remove old plate, re-align, hammer in new plates on both sides?

thanks. 
[image: rafter w loose truss plate]

Comment: "*If this is the only instance of the issue*"?  The joint behind the marked one has no plate at all, and the joint behind that looks like it's popped too.

Comment: @RayButterworth thanks, but no. most of joints only have one plate, and the ones behind have the plate on the opposite side. I will look again though just to be sure.

Comment: thanks for the answers and comments below. I'm going to do some more research, and consider the two suggestions (reapply plate or remove and put new one in) and post an update.

Comment: For my similar roof , I added a short 2X4 with glue and lag screws.

Comment: Looks like somebody tied it together with a board on the other side... If that's the case, might not be anything to worry about...

Comment: @GregNickoloff yea Greg you're right. previous owners put on a new roof. Roofers did some modest improvements in the attic to the truss. In this instance, on the other side, put a sheet of plywood to increase strength and alignment. They didn't bother to put back the nail plate on the other side because it is not necessary. If you post an answer, I'll mark it as correct to give you +score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somebody nailed a board on the other side. If that's the case, it might not be worth worrying about as long as it's done right. I would think 2 or 3 2-2.5" nails in each component would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Those metal plates are “pressed” into the wood members in order to hold the members together and transfer the loads across the truss.

Often, the lumber is a bit “green” (wet) when the truss is assembled. Then, after it’s installed the lumber will dry out and often twist while it dries out. This can cause the metal plate to pop loose. (The plates have short prongs that embed themselves into the lumber.)

Yes, I’d just remove the metal plate, realign the chords (we call them chords, not beams) and then carefully nail a 1/2” plywood gusset on each side of the truss. I’d cut the gusset plate so it extends about 12” down the chord from the joint and nail with about 3 - 6d on each side of each member. (Make sure the nails do not align with nails from the other side of the truss.) Be careful NOT to split the members...otherwise there is no holding power.

Comment: I would probably use the original plate and some pico nails. This is what my truss manufacture reccomends.

Comment: @EdBeal What are pico nails? Is that a “short” nail or a brand?

Comment: The correct type of short fat nails used for hangers. Pico was probably a brand name but the contractors I work with today call them hanger or pico nails.

Comment: @EdBeal Actually, Simpson uses standard “common” nails (and screws).  You can see here in their catalog, pages 26 and 27. https://www.buildsite.com/pdf/simpsonstrongtie/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Wood-Construction-Connectors-1461475.pdf

Comment: I am telling you what the truss manufacturer(s) required for engineered trusses , my shop was 40’ clear span the warehouse was 66’ clear span.  My state is very picky about the engineering stamp and approved plans for trusses any modification must have their approval. If it was a storage shed under 144 sq ft you could use plywood but anything larger requires engineering approval.

Comment: @EdBeal How will the OP find your recommendation of “pico” nails?

Comment: Ask at the hardware store I misspelled it the original name was TICO . But people always understood what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem several times 2 different MFG’s since both buildings were large free span areas I called the MFG. The first connected me to the engineer, he said to use the original plate and then use pico nails in 3 staggered rows on each side. The second time this happened it was on my shop smaller but still 40’ clear span. They said 3 1/2 in from the end then 2 then 3 on each side staggering by 1/4” . They said if I could not do that on my shop they would provide a pair of plates with holes that would meet code. The pico nails held in both cases but I liked the company that offered new drilled plates even though I did not need them. I would find the engineers stamp and call the company as a sharp home inspector can spot patch work and cause problems with a sale.
Correct spelling for the nails is TICO , it was a brand they are now also called joist hanger nails.

Answer (score 0):

1. Smash the metal gusset plate back down into place. Reusing it doesn't count for anything, but removing it would be more work than just leaving it there. It's not worth getting poked and making you bleed everywhere. It'll also keep everything aligned for the next step anyway.
2. Cut a sheet of 25/32" thick plywood into an approximately 2' tall by 3' wide wood triangle gusset plate to fit over the metal gusset plate location.
3. Attach plywood triangle gusset to the truss with 6d common 2" long nails, installed every 3". You could also use structural screws if that's easier for you.
4. If you can put a plywood gusset on both sides, that's even better, but not required. It looks like there is a 2x4 in the way on the other side, so just do one side.